# prove recurrence relation has unique solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Hi everyone doing my last practice problem for finals tomorrow. Would really appreciate if someone can help me understand what this problem is asking.

$$\mathtt show\, that\, a\, kth\,order\,relation\,with\,k,initial\,conditions\,has\,a\,unique\,solution$$

what does it mean by kth order and initial conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k$th order means each term depends on the preceding $k$ terms. $k$ initial conditions means the values of the first $k$ terms.

Comment: ok the order makes sense. Put what does the initial condition mean? is it like if n>0?

Comment: You have a sequence. The sequence has terms. One of them is the first term. Another one is the second term. Another one is the third term. And so on. $k$ initial conditions means the values of the first $k$ terms.